# ReferenceManyField, ReferenceArrayField

Tags: one-to-many, admin-on-rest, graphcool

I'm trying to build a admin app with admin-on-rest connected to Graph.cool. I's working except the relational references. On graph.cool we set up a related field to another "type" and the created fields are array of objects with a related id prop and the related type.

But admin-on-rest spect a single array of ids. I could change my schema but it will broke my database on graph.cool.

I tried some source="??" on the component but no lucky. Any ideias ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That should be handled by the client. I'm afraid it's not implemented yet. You're welcome to give it a try if you like. Otherwise, you'll have to wait until I get some time for it

Comment: thanks! i'm realy trying to solve that because it's essencial for any project.